# Returning blank value from mysql inside < Data >

Tags: php, mysql, sql

```
Mysql I am storing value i a field like :  

<Neha@gmail.com>
```

But when i am accessing it its returning me the blank Value Why this is happening is there any solution related this ??
I there any issue with < > with mysql ???

Comment: How to ask: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: how do you access it?

Comment: simply as we are accessing data in php but its returning me the blank value..

Answer (score 0):

you have to remove <> from the field in order to get correct result via php

Comment: Because these are special characters and when php gets them it does not consider them as a string value